# How to use a custom date field in React (DatePicker)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to use `DatePicker` of `@material-ui/pickers` from React but it doesn't work.
I tried using the exact same code as in the documentation (https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/usage):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns'; // choose your lib
import {
  DatePicker,
  TimePicker,
  DateTimePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
} from '@material-ui/pickers';

export default function Relatorio() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DatePicker value={selectedDate} onChange={handleDateChange} />
      <TimePicker value={selectedDate} onChange={handleDateChange} />
      <DateTimePicker value={selectedDate} onChange={handleDateChange} />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

I get this error (screenshot attached): `The above error occurred in the <MuiPickersUtilsProvider> component`

In codeSandBox it doesn't work with `@date-io/date-fns` versions above `2.0.0`, I am using version `1.3.12` which is supposed to work.

Error message:
[image]

Comment: Hello @Magrini, the error `The above error occurred in the <MuiPickersUtilsProvider> component` is unclear, it only tells you an error happened, the explanation is likely above this message. Can you please check if you find any usefull information about the error itself above this message, and could you edit your question with this information ?

Comment: @Andy, it doesn't say anything useful. Only that I put in the description and about Hooks (but it's already a Hook function)

Comment: Have you tried -1 a fresh install deleting `node_modules`, -2 all components separately one at a time? I can't say more without knowing your package.json and your apps code...